# using minutes and seconds in timedelta

Tags: python, timedelta

I am trying to create a list of datetimes using the datetime and timedelta routines from datetime library (python 2.7).  As an example of my problem I am creating a list with 20 day steps expressed either as days, hours, minutes, or seconds.

I find that the timedelta for minutes and seconds amounting to more than about 30 minutes does not produce the correct timedelta value.  The code below should reproduce the problem.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

atd = np.arange(0,20)
DT = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0)

gain = 1
btd = atd * gain
xTD = [datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in btd]
TD = [(DT+j) for j in xTD]
plt.plot_date(TD, atd)

gain = 24
btd = atd * gain
xTD = [datetime.timedelta(hours=x) for x in btd]
TD = [(DT+j) for j in xTD]
plt.plot_date(TD, atd)
plt.show()

plt.figure()
gain = 1440
btd = atd * gain
xTD = [datetime.timedelta(minutes=x) for x in btd]
TD = [(DT+j) for j in xTD]
plt.plot_date(TD, atd)

gain = 86400
btd = atd * gain
xTD = [datetime.timedelta(seconds=x) for x in btd]
TD = [(DT+j) for j in xTD]
plt.plot_date(TD, atd)

plt.show()
```

Comment: *Does* that code reproduce the problem? I had to set `int(x)` in the calls to `timedelta`, and am now looking at a graph with a diagonal line - what were you expecting to see instead?

Comment: where exactly is the unexpected output? I guess in the last and second last `btd` assignment? What would your expected array look like?

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe. A change to int(x) in the timedelta call for minutes and seconds fixed the problem.    Not sure why this should be the case as the timedelta documentation indicates that you may use floats in the call.

Comment: Just a followup.  Instead of using

Comment: Just a followup.  Instead of fiiing datetime.timedelta(seconds=x) with datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(x)), using datetime.timedelta(seconds=float(x)) also works, though will incur the microsecond rounding error.